# Javascript function is hanging

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to programming. I've been learning HTML, CSS and JavaScript for about 2 weeks now.

As part of my study I need to calculate the tips of two people and compare the averages.

I am currently trying to calculate Marks average, however, when running this the function "hangs" instead of returning the value. Here is the function that is hanging:

```
function determineAverages() {
    let markSum = 0;
    for (i = 0; 0 < mark.tips.length; i++) {
markSum += mark.tips[i]
    }
    let markAverage = markSum / mark.tips.length;
    return markAverage;
}
```

Here is the code overall:

```js
// Calculates the Percent of bills
function calculatePercentOf(percent, bill) {
  let result = Math.floor((percent / 100) * bill);
  return result;
}

// Users
let john = {
  fullName: 'John Smith',
  bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  calcTips: function() {
    this.tips = [];
    this.fullBill = [];
    for (i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
      if (this.bills[i] < 50) {
        this.tips.push(calculatePercentOf(20, this.bills[i]));
      } else if (this.bills[i] >= 50 && this.bills[i] <= 200) {
        this.tips.push(calculatePercentOf(15, this.bills[i]));
      } else if (this.bills[i] > 200) {
        this.tips.push(calculatePercentOf(10, this.bills[i]));
      } else this.tips.push(calculatePercentOf(18, this.bills[i]));

    }
    for (i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
      this.fullBill.push(this.tips[i] + this.bills[i]);
    }
  }
}


let mark = {
  fullName: 'Mark Smith',
  bills: [77, 375, 110, 45],
  calcTips: function() {
    this.tips = [];
    this.fullBill = [];
    for (i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
      if (this.bills[i] < 100) {
        this.tips.push(calculatePercentOf(20, this.bills[i]));
      } else if (this.bills[i] >= 100 && this.bills[i] <= 300) {
        this.tips.push(calculatePercentOf(10, this.bills[i]));
      } else if (this.bills[i] > 300) {
        this.tips.push(calculatePercentOf(25, this.bills[i]));
      } else this.tips.push(calculatePercentOf(18, this.bills[i]));

    }
    for (i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
      this.fullBill.push(this.tips[i] + this.bills[i]);
    }
  }
}


mark.calcTips();
john.calcTips();
console.log(john);
console.log(mark);


// Determine Averages
function determineAverages() {
  let markSum = 0;
  for (i = 0; 0 < mark.tips.length; i++) {
    markSum += mark.tips[i]
  }
  let markAverage = markSum / mark.tips.length;
  return markAverage;
}

console.log(determineAverages());
```

Comment: Please add a `let` in front of all your `i` in `for (let i=` and make sure you actually test `i <` and not `0 <` as you do in your determineAverages

Comment: Just replace `0 < mark.tips.length` with `i<mark.tips.length` in your for loop

Comment: Voting to close as `Not reproducible or was caused by a typo.
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.`

Comment: @VasylMoskalov You can also vote to close with your rep

Comment: as mentioned by @VasylMoskalov fix will solve your infinte loop problem and `mplungjan`  add let in front of `i` to re-initialize in the second loop (code practice)

Comment: Assuming this was caused by a typo from a beginner is totally wrong

Answer (score -2):

You have an infinite loop here

```
function determineAverages() {
 let markSum = 0;
  for (i = 0; 0 < mark.tips.length; i++) {
    markSum += mark.tips[i]
  }
  let markAverage = markSum / mark.tips.length;
  return markAverage;
}
```

This part `0 < mark.tips.length`

0 would always be less than `mark.tips.length` so the loop never stops. You can change that to `i < mark.tips.length` since the variable `i` is used as the iterator to control the loop so your function looks like

Also form the habit of declaring your iterator with a `let` so it can be block scoped

```
function determineAverages() {
 let markSum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < mark.tips.length; i++) {
    markSum += mark.tips[i]
  }
  let markAverage = markSum / mark.tips.length;
  return markAverage;
}
```

Comment: Already explained in full in comment. Please do not answer typo-type questions. OP cannot delete when there are answers

Comment: Apparently the comments might have come up while i was typing my answer. And also, this person is new to programming and obviously needs to know why he is told what to do in the comments. Assuming he made a typo is wrong also because he is learning and might have not know he wasn't supposed to check with 0 and also use a `let`

Comment: The let is not important here. Of course op knew how to test and if not we made it clear. It’s an obvious typo.